# Trying to fetch the unix logs for a given timeframe

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I am struggling to get the logs from a file for a given timeframe.
I have gone through other posts but everywhere the date/time has been hardcoded, I don't want it to be hardcoded and would like to fetch it programatically.

This is what I have been trying.

**This works**,

```
 awk -F, -v b='2016-08-10 00:40:06' -v e='date +"%F %T"' '{ if ($1 >= b && $1 <= e) print}' filename
```

**Whereas this doesn't work,**

```
awk -F, -v b='date --date="10 minutes ago" +"%F %T"' -v e='date +"%F %T"' '{ if ($1 >= b && $1 <= e) print}' filename
```

Not sure why the first Date parameter is not getting calculated on the fly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
 awk -v b="`date --date '10 minutes ago'`"
```

Example:

```
date;echo 1 2 3 |awk -v d="`date --date '10 minutes ago'`" '{print d}'
Wed Aug 10 01:57:23 EDT 2016
Wed Aug 10 01:47:23 EDT 2016

echo 1 2 3 | awk -v d="`date --date '10 minutes ago'`" -v e="`date +%F%T`" '{print d, e}'
Wed Aug 10 01:50:05 EDT 2016 2016-08-1002:00:05
```

Comment: In general, it is better to use the `"$(…)"` notation for [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) than the older ``"`…`"`` notation with back-ticks (which has the additional problem of being hard to enter in Markdown).  It's not critical here since there's no nesting, but it is a good idea to use it in general.